# Find $\int_{\vert z \vert = 1} {dz \over z(e^{1/ z}-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration, singularity

${1 \over z(e^{1/ z}-1)}$ has a succession of isolated singularities $({1 \over 2k \pi} )_{k \in N}$ which converges to 0, then 0 is a non-isolated singularity.

Edit: There is no residue on 0, what to do instead?

Comment: In that case, the function has no residue at $0$. One only has residues at isolated singularities. To evaluate your integral, consider the residue at $\infty$ (equivalently, make the substitution $w = z^{-1}$).

Comment: Ah ok the function has a non isolated singularity so you can't use the residue theorem, what do you use instead? Or is there a way around the hypothesis of the theorem that says the function has to either be holomorphic in z or have an isolated singularity in z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:**

Exploiting Cauchy's Integral Theorem, the value of the integral is unaltered by integrating over $|z|=R>1$.  That is to say,

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z(e^{1/z}-1)}\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=R>1}\frac{1}{z(e^{1/z}-1)}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}\left(e^{\frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}}}-1\right)}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}}\left(1+\frac{1}{2Re^{i\phi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi}Re^{i\phi}\left(1-\frac{1}{2Re^{i\phi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&\to -i\pi\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Alternatively, we can use the Residue at Infinity and write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z(e^{1/z}-1)}\,dz&=-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(e^{1/z}-1)},z=\infty\right)\\\\
&=-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{z^{-1}(e^z-1)},z=0 \right)\\\\
&=2\pi i\left(-\frac12\right)\\\\
&=-i\pi
\end{align}$$

---

> **NOTES:**

We can use [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to write

$$\begin{align}
z(e^{1/z}-1)&=z\left(1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)\right)-z\\\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2z}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Letting $z=Re^{i\phi}$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z(e^{1/z}-1)}&=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{2Re^{i\phi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2Re^{i\phi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)^{-1}\\\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2Re^{i\phi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Then, with $dz=iRe^{i\phi}$, we arrive at the final lines.

Comment: What are you doing in the last two steps?

Comment: In the second to last step, we expand the denominator in reciprocal powers of $Re^{i\phi}$ .  In the last step, we evaluate the first two terms of the expansion (the first one is zero since $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\phi}\,d\phi=0$) and then note that all other terms vanish as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: It's complicated because you used things to solve it that I haven't learned or that I don't understand completely, but I arrived to the same result in another way so I guess your reasoning is right, but I don't know if I should choose it as the correct answer if I don't understand it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: Yes, the second to last step is the one I don't see.

Comment: Christian, I added some notes to elucidate the step about which you had questions.

Comment: I'm not used to work with orders of magnitude, could you elaborate on why the last equality is true?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4 \cdots$$So, we can write this as $1-x+O(x^2)$.  Now let $x=\frac{1}{2Re^{i\phi}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^2e^{i2\phi}}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $z\mapsto\frac1z$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\mapsto-\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}$ but the direction of the contour is reversed. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z\left(e^{1/z}-1\right)}
&=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z\left(e^z-1\right)}\\
&=-\pi i
\end{align}
$$
since
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{z\left(e^z-1\right)}
&=\frac1{z^2\left(1+\frac z2+O\!\left(z^2\right)\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-\frac z2+O\!\left(z^2\right)}{z^2}\\
&=\frac1{z^2}\color{#C00000}{-\frac1{2z}}+O(1)
\end{align}
$$